# Avoiding a javax/ejb/EJBLocalObject exception when mocking with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm attempting to unit test a class that needs a dependency. Creating the dependency class directly is not possible, as the constructor of the dependency has logic that needs objects only available at runtime.

However, when I attempt to mock the dependency class, I get a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBLocalObject" exception. How can I go around this? The only solution I can think of at the moment is to change the ClassToTest to use an interface instead of the actual concrete Dependency class.

Some code to illustrate how I'm currently attempting to mock the dependency:

```
package mockTest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;

public class MockTest {

    @Test
    public void performTest() {
        // Mock the dependency and create the class to test
        Dependency dependency = PowerMockito.mock(Dependency.class);
        ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(dependency);

       // Invoke a method in classToTest, assert..
    }
}
```

Further clarification:

Q: Is the Dependent class an impl of an interface?

ClassToTest (the dependent class) is a concrete class and implements no interfaces, although it easily could - I control the source. The Dependency class is a concrete class that does not implement interfaces and I have no control over the source.

Q: Are you only passing in the "dependency" object because it gets created in the normal constructor, so by providing one, you try and privde the working Mock instead of the created one?

Yes. ClassToTest uses methods of Dependency that cause the Dependency to e.g. make JDBC calls. I want to be able to either pass in the actual Dependency (from the implementation code) or a mock (from the test code).

Q: Is the dependency a static?

No, the Dependency or the methods in the Dependency are not static.

Comment: 1. Is the Dependent class an impl of an interface?
2. Are you only passing in the "dependency" object because it gets created in the normal constructor, so by providing one, you try and privde the working Mock instead of the created one? 3. Is the dependency a static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, this issue appears to be related to the way Maven is used to build the project I'm working on.

The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is thrown because the Maven artifact that contains javax.ejb.EJBLocalObject has the Maven scope 'provided'. This causes the use of the Dependency object to work in implementation code at run-time. However, when the test code attempts to mock Dependency, the Maven artifact is not available and the NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

A quick way to resolve the issue would be to add something that contains javax.ejb.EJBLocalObject as a Maven dependency with test scope to the POM, for example:

```
<!--Provides javax.ejb.EJBLocalObject to tests, enabling mocking of Dependency-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jboss</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-j2ee</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a class constructor that requires a ton of dependent objects (singleton static at runtime, etc.) is always a pain when creating mock tests.  The best way I can think of is to use some combination of the `Powermockito.whenNew()` call, and the `Mockito.any(Class.class)` call.  This way, when your constructor is called, you can hook in the objects that are needed.
If you follow a similar singleton pattern on your dependent objects, you can mock those classes `getInstance()` calls to return you a copy of a mock you instantiate in the tests.

Example:

```
Dependency dependMock = PowerMockito.mock(Dependency.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Dependency.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(dependMock);
```

OR, if the `Dependency` needs args passed in for your 2nd level dependency:

```
Dependency dependMock = PowerMockito.mock(Dependency.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(Dependency.class)
  .withArguments(Mockito.any(LevelTwoDependency.class)).thenReturn(dependMock);
```

Note, that when using the `whenNew` you need to have a hook for the class you are testing, so that code gets fired off.  This can be done by adding some mock annotations for the test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassYouAreTesting.class})
public class ClassTest{
    // code    
}
```

This allows you to have full control over your 2nd level dependency objects with Mocks.  By removing them from logic (by providing Mocked functionality), you get to the core of your tests, which ends up testing the pure functionality of your class in question.  By removing any odd behavior from these dependent classes, you remove the risk of having bugs in that code, which would end up breaking and giving false test results for any class using those dependency classes.

By chainging together these Mocks, you can basically mock the main dependent class and all its sub-dependency classes using other mocks.  It can get a little messy depending on how the constrcutors work and you you setup private variables for these objects.

Comment: The "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBLocalObject" exception occurs already when creating the dependency; so when I do "Dependency dependMock = PowerMockito.mock(Dependency.class);" in the test code, the exception is thrown. Thus, while these points are useful, they do not unfortunately resolve the issue.